# c++ file doesnt open right

Tags: c++, file

```
[Project]
FileName=sjkabljt
Name=sukablyat
Type=1
Ver=2
ObjFiles=
Includes=
Libs=
PrivateResource=
ResourceIncludes=
MakeIncludes=
Compiler=
CppCompiler=
Linker=
IsCpp=1
Icon=
ExeOutput=
ObjectOutput=
LogOutput=
LogOutputEnabled=0
OverrideOutput=0
OverrideOutputName=
HostApplication=
UseCustomMakefile=0
CustomMakefile=
CommandLine=
Folders=
IncludeVersionInfo=0
SupportXPThemes=0
CompilerSet=0
CompilerSettings=0000000000000000101000000
UnitCount=1

[VersionInfo]
Major=1
Minor=0
Release=0
Build=0
LanguageID=1033
CharsetID=1252
CompanyName=
FileVersion=
FileDescription=Developed using the Dev-C++ IDE
InternalName=
LegalCopyright=
LegalTrademarks=
OriginalFilename=
ProductName=
ProductVersion=
AutoIncBuildNr=0
SyncProduct=1

[Unit1]
FileName=files\siplasplas\sukablyat.cpp
CompileCpp=1
Folder=
Compile=1
Link=1
Priority=1000
OverrideBuildCmd=0
BuildCmd=
```

this is what i get after i open the .cpp file....the file was supposed to get 10 numbers into a[x]; then display them from x+1 to x+10 and then from x+10 to x+1
after that make the sum of all the numbers, and then locate the min and max number....after the program was written i tested it and it all worked...then clicked the top left corner icon and clicked SAVE FILE AS, after that i entered a name and pressed enter while i saved it to desktop to upload it to my schools homework site...so is there anyway to get the code out of this file, or will i have to re write all the lines D: ?

Comment: please somebody answer

Comment: please somebody provide some code for us to look at.

Comment: i lost the code because this file has opened...okay?

Comment: please edit your question with information about your operating system and the development environment.

Comment: windows 8.1 64bit and i did it on c++ 5.9 ...

Comment: and this happened only this one time..i tried with another random programe and it worked normaly...so idk what happened before..but is there any way i can get the code back?

Comment: ***so is there anyway to get the code out of this file, or will i have to re write all the lines***  No there is no code in the file you put in the question. You will have to rewrite your code.

Comment: What is C++ 5.9?  As I recall, there is C++03, C++11 and C++14.  I use IAR Workbench, Microsoft Visual Studio and Eclipse CDT as IDEs, what are you using?

Comment: I assume that is a Dev-C++ version.

Comment: Which IDE?  What is the name of it?  Can you go to the "Help | About" and find the name?  Or does the name show up on the title bar?  What is the name of the executable?  Are you using Code::Blocks?  Are you using an editor and command line compiler, such as G++?

Comment: DEV-C++ 5.9.0 IDE ...pls answer me..can i get the code out of that file or no?

Comment: ***clicked the top left corner icon and clicked SAVE FILE AS*** You need to be careful when you overwrite a file. It looks like you told the IDE to overwrite your c++ source code with a copy of your project file.

Comment: ***can i get the code out of that file or no?*** I say no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file you're providing us with is apparently a .dev file, used by Dev-C++.  It is used for projects, like Visual C++'s .vcxproj or (sort of) a Makefile used with g++.  http://www.file-extensions.org/dev-file-extension-dev-c-project-file

Somehow you saved that .dev file over your source .cpp file.  When you overwrite a file, the old version is gone.  You'll be well advised to keep backup copies (I copy the entire folder with all its files) in case something strange like this happens again.  Sorry you lost your code.

Comment: Maybe the OP should turn off the windows option to "hide extensions for known types". My guess is the hiding of the extension played a part since I expect the project file and the c++ source file to have the same name but different extension.

Comment: Yes.  Definitely -- turn off "hide extensions"!

Answer (score 2):

As has been stated in the comments, there is no way to recover the code now that the file has been overwritten/was not saved correctly.